# Restart Timer after .cancel()

Tags: java, android

How can I restart my timer after I called the .cancel method ?
My Timer is declared in my onCreate method.

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                --standby_zaehler;
                if(standby_zaehler < 0) {
                    rndm_groesse = stand_by.length;
                    random_zahl = r.nextInt(rndm_groesse);
                    speakOut(stand_by[random_zahl]);

                    for (;;)
                    {
                        standby_zaehler = r.nextInt(60);
                        if (standby_zaehler >= 15)
                            break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);
```

somewhere else I call

> timer.cancel();

But I want  to start it again after the cancel but dont know how . Is there a way ?

Comment: no. that what the doc says. create a new timer

Comment: put that entire first code block in a method then call that method to start the timer

Comment: According to the doc:

 cancel()
Cancels the TimerTask and removes it from the Timer's queue.

As it's removed from the Timer's queue you would have to make a new one.

Comment: or cancel your timertask

Answer (score 0):

The way you can do that is by re-instantiating the TimerTask that you are running every time you want to rerun the timer after cancelling it, because cancelling it also cancels the TimerTask associated with it.
Additionally you need to make a boolean to check whether the timer is on or not, so that if it is on, just cancel it, if not then re-instantiate the task and the timer (both) otherwise you will get the exception that you are probably takling about
i wrote you this code as an example, and i tried it, worked perfectly

```
Timer timer;
boolean timerOn = false;

@FXML
private void setTimer(ActionEvent event) { 
    if (timerOn) {
        timer.cancel();
        timerOn = false;
    } else {
        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask runBlinking = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                blinkCircle();
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(runBlinking, 1, Long.parseLong(txt_seconds.getText()));  
        timerOn = true;
    }      
}
```